# Disable controls using .not selection Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to disable all the controls in the div except certain controls.

here is the div

```
<div id="vehicleDetails" class="form-group" class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Vehicle Details</h3>
        <span class="pull-right clickable">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <!--h3 class="panel-title">Vehicle Details</h3-->
            <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
                <label for="fldVIN" >VIN</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="fldVIN" data-bind="value:VIN" class="form-control" placeholder="Search VIN to retrieve the details"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-secondary" id="searchVINBtn" data-bind="event: {click: getCRMorDMSDetails}">Go !</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
                <label for="fldEngine" >Engine number</label>
                <input type="text" id="fldEngine" data-bind="value:ENGINE_NUMBER" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
                <label for="fldChassis" >Chassis number</label>
                <input type="text" id="fldChassis" data-bind="value:CHASSIS_NUMEBR" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
                <label for="fldInvoice" >Invoice number</label>
                <input type="text" id="fldInvoice" data-bind="value:INVOICE_NUMBER" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
                <label for="fldRegdNo" >Regd number</label>
                <input type="text" id="fldRegdNo" data-bind="value:REGD_NUMBER" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
                <label for="fldOrderFrom" >Date of Sale</label>
                <input type="date" id="fldOrderFrom" data-bind="date:DATE_OF_SALE" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <!--
                                                  <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
                                                     <label for="fldCurrentKM" >Current KM</label>
                                                     <input type="text" id="fldCurrentKM" data-bind="value:CURRENT_KM" class="form-control"/>
                                                  </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i try to not disable two controls by using the below jquery,but it works only for the fldVIN control.

```
$('#vehicleDetails :input').not('#fldVIN','#searchVINBtn').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: try like .not('#fldVIN, #searchVINBtn')

Comment: What about `$('#vehicleDetails :input').not('#fldVIN').not('#searchVINBtn').attr('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#vehicleDetails :input').not('#fldVIN,#searchVINBtn').attr('disabled', true);
```